# Working with colons inside array keys, or how to avoid it

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, special-characters

I am being passed an array by an identity management system (SAML2.0 based) which provides me a set of user attributes in an array.

The identity provider configures the structure of this data, and I am providing this (much larger company) with a service. Altering the way I receive this array is not in my control.

The array arrives with me in this form (this is what I see if I `print_r` the array):

```
Array
(
[http://longurl/surname] => Array ([0] => Smith)
[http://longurl/firstname] => Array ([0] => John)
);
```

As you can see, the keys to this array of arrays is a URL (I'm sure they have a good reason?!). However if I try to work with this array like so:

```
echo 'Hello Mr. '.$SAMLDATA[http://longurl/surname][0];
```

This is no good, because colons aren't valid characters inside variables (or so I read).

Escaping the character doesn't seem to work, any idea what I can do here? Many thanks.

Comment: If you do not quote them, I suspect you don't have `error_reporting` turned on. Otherwise, you would be seeing piles and piles of notices about unknown constants, assumed strings. `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` always, when developing.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Ah, ok thank you. Will quoting the string work if I wanted to define an array with such a string (for testing purposes?)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski - yes I see it will, this has fixed my problem. Thank you. I confess I don't understand the difference between $array[data] and $array['data'] - I've seen people on stack irately dismiss the quote marks as unnecessary - so I got out of the habit, but I should learn when to use them. Thanks again - if you write up a short answer I'll mark you up.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski additionally I shall take your advice on the error reporting.

Comment: sure I'll put in an answer.  Non-numeric array keys _must_ be quoted, since they are strings.  PHP will _kindly_ assume you meant to quote them if you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP's *non-integer* array keys are *strings*, they must be quoted as strings.  If you do not quote them, PHP will issue an `E_NOTICE` about undefined constants, assuming you meant to use a string in place of the constant, and if you attempt to use an array key with a colon like those URLs, it will likely result in a fatal syntax error.

So to fix your issue, you really only need to correctly quote the array keys as in:

```
echo 'Hello Mr. '.$SAMLDATA['http://longurl/surname'][0];
```

Note that the only circumstance in which it is acceptable *not* to quote string array keys is when interpolated inside a double-quote string.  For example:

```
$str = "This double-quoted string has an $array[key] value inside it";
```

For simple array values like the above, you need not quote the key in a double-quoted string.

However, in your case, you will probably need to use the `{}` syntax to access one of these URL keys in an interpolated string.  When using `{}` you *will* need to quote the string array keys.  Generally I always recommend using the `{}` syntax for array and object values, as it improves readability:

```
// When using {} enclosures, you do need to quote the key
$str = "This double-quoted string has an {$array['key']} value inside it";
```

The various rules surrounding the above examples in double-quoted strings [are documented here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Comment: `$str = "This double-quoted string has an {$array['key']} value inside it";`

Here you have quoted the key, contrary to your explanation, was this a slip? Or have I misunderstood...?

Comment: @Gideon Note the comment above it.  When inside `{}` you do need to quote the string. I'll clarify the paragraph above more, because it isn't explicit enough.

Comment: Ah - thank you for clarifying, and pointing me towards that documentation, I'll have a read.